# Split char * with strtok in C++

Tags: c++, split, char, strtok

I have to do this exercise for a course.

```
class Cadena{
protected:
char * s;
bool I;
}
```

The `char * s` has the following style: `“text1:text2::text3:”` and I need to generate a list (`Lista<Cadena>`) by splitting the `char *` when there is a `:` and every time I get a `::` I must add a `“@EMPTY@”` to the list I’m generating and if it ends with a `:` I need to add a `“@EMPTY@”` at the end of my list.

Right now I have this two methods, `dividirTupla` works just fine and does everything I need but as you can see it isn’t the “nicest” code ever, while `split` does most of what I need but I can’t realize when the `char *` I’m given has `::` so I can add an `“@EMPTY@”` to my list in the correct place.

Is there any way I could do that? So the second method could work instead of using the first and messy one.

```
    Lista<Cadena>* Cadena::dividirTupla(){
        if(s!=NULL){
            Lista<Cadena> *ret=new ListaImp<Cadena>();
            int ppio=0;
            int fin=0;
            //Go over the char * in order to find the :
            for(int i=0; i<strlen(s); i++){
                if(s[i]==':'){
                    //If there is a ::
                    if(ppio==fin){
                        ret->AgregarFin("@EMPTY@");
                    }else{
                        //If we find a : we add the substring to our list
                        string a=((string)s).substr(ppio,fin-ppio);
                        char * dato = new char[a.length() + 1];
                        strcpy(dato,a.c_str());
                      //It adds the char * to the list
                        ret->AgregarFin(dato);
                        delete dato;
                    }
                    fin++;
                    ppio=fin;
                }else{
                    fin++;
                }
            }
            //Add the last text
            if(ppio<strlen(s)){
                string a=((string)s).substr(ppio,strlen(s));
                char * dato = new char[a.length() + 1];
                strcpy(dato,a.c_str());
                ret->AgregarFin(dato);
                delete dato;
            }
            //If it ends in : add the @EMPTY@
            if(s[strlen(s)-1]==':'){
                ret->AgregarFin("@EMPTY@");
            }
            cout<<*ret;
            return ret;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    Lista<Cadena>* Cadena::split(){
        if(s!=NULL){
            char * aux=strtok(s,":");
            Lista<Cadena> *ret=new ListaImp<Cadena>();
            while(aux != NULL){
                ret->AgregarFin(aux);
                aux= strtok(NULL, ":");
            }
            return ret;
        }else{
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What a nightmare. You know, if you were given the same requirements, but were told to do this using C++ (using the standard library), it would still be a good exercise. Instead you're told to do this with such error-prone, low-level logic.  You might as well do this in 'C'.  What a shame.

Comment: Looks like they are doing it in C...    (Note: C++ isn't "C with lists"!)

Comment: Oh ok I see. I changed the tag for C. Thanks!

Comment: No, the code is C++, but it doesn't use any of the facilities that C++ has to offer. It is basically 'C' with a few C++ keywords thrown in (such as `new` and `delete`), plus it has this `Lista` type which is unknown.  One thing, please use `std::string` throughout the code.  Don't start to use `char* new[]` just for the sake of it.  You're using `std::string`, and then for some odd reason, you switch right back to using `new char[]`.  Why?

Comment: OK. I read your requirements. It is just a colon-delimited string parser. All you need to do is tokenize the string, and rebuild a new string with the word `@EMPTY@` if there is no token found. There are scores of better ways of doing this using honest C++, not C with classes. If you're interested in C++ oriented answers, please say so. Otherwise, I don't think anyone will try to wade through your code as it stands now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The class `Cadena` was given to me, so I must use `char *` instead of string, but since I couldn't find any method with `char*` I parse it to `string`. Right now all I can do is use C with classes, but I will try to figure out what you said about rebuilding the string, I just don't get how I figure out where did I had :: after tokenizing.

Comment: I think I got something for you...

Comment: A tokeniser would return TEXT & DELIM tokens, with strings pointing to what was matched by the token.  Then you'ld parse each line, deciding what to do, depending on whether the previous token was a DELIM or TEXT or ENDL.  It's going to be a very structured solution, and you don't need it for "simple" string processing.

Comment: @Rob11311 - Once the requirements were deciphered, there are better C++ and even 'C' solutions than what the OP posted.  So I'm not surprised if you or someone else comes up with a more C-based solution than a "pure" C++ one.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  The key thing is the first sentence in the question "exercise", it sounds like a bottom up byte shovelling course, rather than a higher level conceptual one.  Submitting a really elegant Haskell solution, plus the C code of the compiler, is even less likely to get a pass, than a high level C++ solution; because it's hiding what the course is aimed at teaching.  Yet it's likely to be a much more beautiful solution

Comment: Thank everyone for your answers, I will try everything and if I get it to work I will post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to prove Paul wrong ;)   Can you use, `strstr` instead?

If not, I'd just re-write strtok, myself to return a structure, so the NULL error case, and the 0 length match can be differentiated, in calling code.

With strstr, something roughly like (though there will be bugs like ":xx:xx" lines for you to fix) ..

Scan for delimiter ":", when found rescan for a repeated one "::"
If we have repeats, copy out the EMPTY marker, and look again for "::"

copyFromUntil, should save token from first up to 2nd char * pointer.

strstr - locate a substring  see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr

```
//
// Handle stuff like "", "xxx", "xx::xx:::xx:xx::::xxx" and "xx::xx:::xx:xx::::xxx:"
//
// first find a ":", then check if it's "::"
char *delim, *repeateddelim;
while ((delim  = strstr( s, ":") != NULL) {

    // Process from s..delim
    copyFromUntil( s, delim);

    // Scan for repeated delimiter's eg) : in "xx::xx:::xx:xx::::xxx"
    while (delim == (repeateddelim = strstr( delim, "::")) {

        // Insert the empty delimitter marker
        copyFromUntil( EMPTY_STR, EMPTY_END);

        /* Resume scan from 2nd ':'
        s = delim = repeateddelim;
    }
    // At a single ":" now, move past, saving delim pos
    lastdelim = delim;
    s= delim+1;
}
// From start of line or last ":" to EOL
if (s) {
    if (strlen(s) == 0 && (s == lastdelim+1) {    //  one past a delimiter?
        copyFromUntil( EMPTY_STR, EMPTY_END);
    } else {
        copyFromUntil( s, s + strlen(s));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will try this or something similar to see if it works

Comment: If you're allowed 2 passes, then you could use strstr on ::, rebuilding string from xxx:xx::xx to xxx:xx:@EMPTY@:xx, then use the strtok approach you already wrote. still leaves :xx: cases to handle though.